# Create nested output

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've just started playing with D3.js and I can't seem to figure out how to create a nested structure based on my data.

Current code:

```
var g = svg.append("g").attr("class","top").selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter()

var link = g.append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.color })
    .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });

link.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.title; });

var bbox = link.node().getBBox();

link.append("rect")
  .attr("class","rect")
  .attr("x", function() { return Math.floor(bbox.x + bbox.width/2.0) - 26; })
  .attr("y", function() { return Math.floor(bbox.y + bbox.height/2.0) - 26; })
  .attr("width", "52")
  .attr("height", "52")
  .attr("fill", "black");

link.append("svg:image")
  .attr("class","image")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return Math.floor(bbox.x + bbox.width/2.0) - 25; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return Math.floor(bbox.y + bbox.height/2.0) - 25; })
  .attr("width", "50")
  .attr("height", "50")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.image; });

var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(function(d) { return d; })
        .on("dragstart", function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
        .on("drag", dragmove)
    );

function dragmove(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + (d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - d.dy, d3.event.y))) + ")");
    sankey.relayout();
    link.attr("d", path);
}
```

This gives the structure

```
<g>
    <path ... >
        <title ... >
        <rect ... >
        <image ... >
    <path ... >
        <title ... >
        <rect ... >
        <image ... >
</g>
```

but what I want is

```
<g>
    <g>
        <path ... >
            <title ... >
        <rect ... >
        <image ... >
    </g>
    <g>
        <path ... >
            <title ... >
        <rect ... >
        <image ... >
    </g>
</g>
```

because then I can show and hide the rectangle and image. All attempts I've done so far have broken the dragmove functionality....

**Edit**: jsFiddle of current state [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KcRjP/2/)

Comment: Are the nested <g> elements meant to represent the nodes? Are you saying you want the elements created from the links data to be nested inside the corresponding nodes-data <g>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending rectangle and images to `link` variable. You should be appending them to g.
Give this a try:

```
var gEnter = svg.append("g").attr("class","top").selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter()


var g = gEnter.append("g");

var link = g.append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.color });

link.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.title; });

var bbox = link.node().getBBox();

g.append("rect")
  .attr("class","rect")
  .attr("x", function() { return Math.floor(bbox.x + bbox.width/2.0) - 26; })
  .attr("y", function() { return Math.floor(bbox.y + bbox.height/2.0) - 26; })
  .attr("width", "52")
  .attr("height", "52")
  .attr("fill", "black");

g.append("svg:image")
  .attr("class","image")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return Math.floor(bbox.x + bbox.width/2.0) - 25; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return Math.floor(bbox.y + bbox.height/2.0) - 25; })
  .attr("width", "50")
  .attr("height", "50")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.image; });
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I've tried that before, but it results in the following structure: <g class="top"><g><rect ..><image ..></g><g><rect ..><image ..></g><g><path .. ><path ... ></g></g> in other words all the paths are appended to the last nested <g>.

Comment: There was a simple mistake in my code. I have corrected it now. It should have been `var g = gEnter.append("g");`. I am pretty sure this should give you the desired hirerarchy. If possible can you create a jsfiddle and I can see what actually you are trying to do.

Comment: I corrected for that typo myself, should have mentioned that. Added jsFiddle link to description

Comment: My solution was almost correct, except that I didn't take into account the sorting you added to the end of paths. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KcRjP/3/

Comment: Thank you again for your quick reply. I wasn't aware of the effect sorting had (never used d3 before). You've answered the main point of my question, so I will mark this as the correct answer. However, the image coordinates aren't where I'd expect them. Could you add a comment on how to get the bounding box of the path the image belongs to? ..